# How to create multiple instances for an inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

consider the following code

```
class A
 {
 Class B
  {
    ...
  }
 psvm()
  {
    B b= new A().new B(); //this one works
    B b[]=new A().new B[size]; //compile error
  }
```

how to go about?

Comment: @MadProgrammer,, I was thinking about hashtable implementation where the outer class is hashtable and inner class would be index nodes pointing to their respective chains,, is this correct?? btw , i didn't understand your comment...

Answer (score 3):

You're creating an array of `B`s. That is, you are creating a data structure that can store references to `B` objects. That data structure is not a `B` and therefore does not need an `A` to exist.

```
B b[] = new B[size];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like...

```
A.B[] c = new A.B[size];
```

But `B` may need to be declared `public` if you want to access it from outside the context of the package it is declared...

You can also import `B`

```
import your.awesome.packages.A.B;
```

Which will allow you to use...

```
B[] c = new B[10];
```